# How to make the Floating Action Button scroll off the screen or disappear

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I've seen some apps with a RecyclerView and a Floating Action Button and when you scroll down the RecyclerView the Floating Action Button will scroll off from the bottom or just minimize and disappear. I have created a RecyclerView and a FloatingActionButton in a CoordinatorLayout using the design support library. But the FloatingActionButton doesn't do anything when I scroll. Is there a way to add an attribute in the layout XML file to achieve this, or can I write some Java codes to do this? And how?

Comment: you mean like this?  https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part3%29/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for doing this you have to create custom `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` class..

here is what I did.

```
public abstract class HidingScrollListener extends
    RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
private static final int HIDE_THRESHOLD = 20;
private int scrolledDistance = 0;
private boolean controlsVisible = true;

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

    if (scrolledDistance > HIDE_THRESHOLD && controlsVisible) {
        onHide();
        controlsVisible = false;
        scrolledDistance = 0;
    } else if (scrolledDistance < -HIDE_THRESHOLD && !controlsVisible) {
        onShow();
        controlsVisible = true;
        scrolledDistance = 0;

    }

    if ((controlsVisible && dy > 0) || (!controlsVisible && dy < 0)) {
        scrolledDistance += dy;
    }
}

public abstract void onHide();

public abstract void onShow();
```

And in your MainActivity

```
rv.setOnScrollListener(new HidingScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShow() {
            fam.animate().translationY(0)
                    .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2)).start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onHide() {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) fam
                    .getLayoutParams();
            int fabMargin = lp.bottomMargin;
            fam.animate().translationY(fam.getHeight() + fabMargin)
                    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2)).start();
        }
    });
```

Where `rv` would be your `RecyclerView` and `fam` would be your FAB.

Hope it will help you.